# bitcoin-core building disabled binaries

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, compiling, raspberry-pi

good day,
I have just tried upgrading to core 24. As I am looking for a purely headless bitcoin-core, my process was the following

```
rm -rf bitcoin
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin
./autogen.sh
/configure --without--gui --disable-wallet --disable-tests --without-miniupnpc  --enable-fuzz-binary=no --disable-man --without--gui --without-natpmp --disable-bench
make && sudo make install
```

My understanding is that this should not build bitcoin-qt as well, which is, however, built as well?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You have `--without--gui` instead of `--without-gui`, could that be the problem?

Comment: "make" only the targets you need, instead of the default target